# How can I avoid a brick to the back of the head?

Tags: h2g2-30th-anniversary

I was lying down in front of a bulldozer - so far so good. Ford came and gave me a towel, which I accepted. He then wandered off, but when I got up to follow him, The bulldozer demolished my house, and I was killed by a stray flying brick. [How do I proceed](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/articles/1g84m0sXpnNCv84GpN2PLZG/the-hitchhiker-s-guide-to-the-galaxy-game-30th-anniversary-edition) after taking the towel from Ford?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not accept the towel from Ford.  Just keep waiting and you will be able to continue.